# Cypress tests in docker image are dependent on URL format

Tags: cypress

i have run cypress tests in the following scenarios:

1. Cypress tests in windows ui version against local installation: https://localdomain/site..  (localdomain resolves to 127.0.0.1) tests pass
2. Cypress tests in windows ui version against remote server site: https://subdomain.domain.de tests pass
3. Cypress tests in docker image against local installation: tests pass
4. Cypress tests in docker image against remote server site:
   CypressError: The application redirected to [remote site] more than 20 times.

To further investigate this problem i have made a local installation with a domain resolving to 127.0.0.1 of the form subdomain.domain.de. With this domain the tests also fail with the same error.
I am using the image cypress/included:12.2.0. There is no problem with certificates, different browsers lead to the same result. There is indeed a redirect to another page on the site, but not between different domains or subdomains.

Cypress seems to behave differently depending on the url format.
Does anyone have any idea about this?

Thanks!